# remove ID from URL in htaccess

Tags: redirect

I tried to do this myself, but I am a newbie with regex.

I have this URL:

```
http://[DOMAIN]/[category]/27466-some-article-is-here
```

Which should redirect to this URL:

```
http://[DOMAIN]/[category]/some-article-is-here
```

I simply want to remove the ID from the URL. The category could be anything, which I want to keep.

How do I achieve this?

UPDATE:
I adjusted the Redirect from @taduuda to this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/[\d]*\-(.*)$ $1/$
```

This looks good with a testing tool, but this still doesn't work on my wordpress site.

My htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# BEGIN - Custom Redirects
RedirectMatch 301 /heute(.*) /$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/[\d]*\-(.*)$ $1/$2
# END - Custom Redirects

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will work with every URL you have, but this whould give you a base to work off of. Note that this sepcifically checks for 5 digit IDs. If you want this to be more flexible, simply change `{5}` to a different quatifier like `*`. Also note that this might match URLs you don't want to redirect.

> * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Your rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)\/[\d]{5}\-(.*)$ $1/$2
```

Or a more precise variant to avoid unwanted redirects:

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*example\.com\/.+)(?:\/[\d]{5})\-(.*)$ $1/$2
```

Since you mentioned that you're new to regex, here are some tools that will help you get started:

Online Regex building/testing tool: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

Online .htaccess rewrite testing tool: [htaccess.madewithlove.be](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately this didn't work properly, even as I was changing it a bit. I used `RewriteRule ^(.*)\/[\d]*\-(.*)$ $1/$2`, which looks right with the testing tool, but doesn't work on my site. Any suggestions?

Comment: The regex does not seem to be the problem then. A few questions: Where are you trying to implement the .htaccess? Are your sure your webserver allows to change settins via .htaccess? And, since you are using Wordpress, have you tried changing the [settings for the permalinks in Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen) itself ?

Comment: I added the redirects to the .htaccess in root. I already did another redirect, which was working. And changing the settings for permalinks is no option, because we are transfering the site from Joomla to WordPress and the Joomla-IDs don't match the WordPress-IDs

Comment: Could you add the content of your .htaccess to your question? The two redirects might be interfering with oneanother.

Comment: My bad, you'd need to use redirect rather than rewrite. Try setting it up with my edited answer.